# Experience with traveling to and from Split to Hvar during off season

Tags: croatia, split

I'm looking to travel from Split to Hvar for a day trip (October 7th during off peak season) via Catamaran but I've been having issues trying to find an updated timetable on departures and arrivals. I've only found 1 site that is selling tickets for a round trip that is aligned with what I'm looking for. The site site however shows a time table without that same time and I'm not sure if it is worth risking it. Has anyone that has traveled from Split to Hvar and back during offseason times share their experience on this?

Edit: I'm looking to arrive early in the morning and leave as late as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by 'better', faster, cheaper, more secure?

Comment: Risking what?  Which site shows a timetable without the time you're looking for?  What time are you looking for, in fact?  By the way, I've done this several times during the peak season and always bought my tickets at the ferry terminal.  I don't suppose you're less likely to be able to do that during the off season.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the timetable of Jadrolinijas catamaran on their site:

Split to Hvar (town) on 7th October:

- Depatures at 09:30, 11:30 and 14:00
- arrival 65 min later
- https://www.jadrolinija.hr/hr/schedule/LineSearchResults/Index/2331792/2331746/07102019

Back from Hvar (town) to Split on the same day:

- Depatures at 06:35, 12:30 and 14:00
- arrival 65 min later
- https://www.jadrolinija.hr/hr/schedule/LineSearchResults/Index/2331746/2331792/07102019

Krilo has two more lines:

- Split-Hvar-Split: leaving Split at 10:00 h, arrival 50 minutes later. Back from Hvar at 12:00 h, https://www.krilo.hr/en/sailing-schedule/split-hvar/
- Split – Brač (Milna) – Hvar – Korčula – Mljet (Pomena) – Dubrovnik: leaving Split at 07:40 h, arrival 60 minutes later. Back from Hvar at 19:10 h. https://www.krilo.hr/en/sailing-schedule/split-dubrovnik/